# CakePHP 3.x calling standard validation rules in own validation rules

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

How can I call the CakePHP 3.x built-in 'rule'=>'email' inside of my own validation rule? I would like to make this check among other customized checks not in e.g. validationDefault function.

```
public function myValidationRule($value,$context){   
   // HERE -- how can I call standard email rule
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for `requirePresence`, `allowEmpty` and `notEmpty`, all built-in rules map to corresponding static methods on the `\Cake\Validation\Validation` class, which you can invoke manually yourself if necessary.

The `email` rule uses `Validation::email()`, so you can use it like

```
public function myValidationRule($value, $context) {   
   // ...
   $isValid = \Cake\Validation\Validation::email($value);
   // ...
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Validation > Core Validation Rules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#core-validation-rules)**
- **[API > \Cake\Validation\Validation::email()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_email)**

Answer (score 0):

```
public function myValidationRule($value,$context){   
   // HERE -- you can get your email in $value and other values in $context
   // HERE you can add any of your custome validation rule 
   // for example
   return $value==null;
   // it will return true if your email is null.
}
```